# How to use gulp to watch changes happened in A directory and apply the same changes to B directory?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I want to use gulp to watch changes happened in A directory and apply the same changes to B directory.

Initially, I'll copy everything under directory A into directory B.

The changes can be:

- modify a file
- add a file
- delete a file
- add a directory
- delete a directory

I'm unable to use gulp-watch to achieve the above tasks. Gulp-watch can't detect a file is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but this is what I just finished writing for myself:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    removeFiles = require("gulp-remove-files"),
    watch = require("gulp-watch");

gulp.task("default", function() {
    gulp.watch("./assets/**/*.*", function() {
        gulp.run("update-static");
    });
});

gulp.task("update-static", function() {
    // copy assets
    gulp.src("./_static/assets/**/*.*")
    .pipe(removeFiles());
    gulp.src("./assets/**/*.*")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./_static/assets"));
});
```

I'm super new to task runners, so I'm not entirely sure this will work. You'll of course need to modify the paths and everything as you require.